# Root Android Tablet without USB Cable

Tags: rooting

I have a tablet and its USB port is not working, I think it is broken or there is some hardware problem. I can not plug USB cable in it.

Now my problem is, I want to root my tablet can I do that without using USB cable. And can I use bluetooth, wifi or HDMI for this purpose.

There is a similar post (see link below) and it has answers put they are not applicable because they are suggesting some apps from market but these app will work only on rooted devices.

[Get root or re-install the OS without a USB cable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27765/get-root-or-re-install-the-os-without-a-usb-cable)

Comment: This will likely be very dependent on what kind of device you have and/or what version of Android it's running. Providing that information would be helpful.

Comment: How are you charging the device?

Comment: It has a separate port for charger.

Comment: What device is this? And does it have an SD Card slot? Some methods of rooting require booting into the Recovery mode and installing a specific update.zip file.

Comment: It is Ampe A90 china made tab and yes it has SD Card Slot. @dymutaos can you please tell me complete procedure

Answer (score 1):

What is your android version?

If it is below 3.x, then you could use the browser to download one of these apps:

- Univeral Androot (desinged for android 2.2)
- z4root (desinged for android 2.2)
- [Gingerbreak](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1044765) (designed for Android 2.3.x)

If it is above 3.x, then you cannot use this method, as Google patched the method used in these cracks.

Comment: ICS Android 4.0.1. I have tries Z4root but it did not work. I did not know it was for 2.2

Comment: There is **no way** to root ICS 'easily', as Google patched the exploit used in all the apps and programs. You will have to get the hardware fixed if you would like to root.